# iOS: is there anyway to post events to the system, not just to the current application?

Tags: ios, events

I'm curious if there's a way in iOS to post events to the system, like touch or button press events. By posting to the system, I mean any application can receive them, including elements like the notification or control center.

I figure this requires an undocumented API, and that's fine. This is just for my own personal projects and curiosity, and not for something I would ever try to submit to the app store.

I'd love it if there was a way to do this without jailbreaking the device. However, if that's not possible (say because the undocumented API for doing this requires a private Apple entitlement) I'm open to methods that work for jailbroken devices.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without jailbreaking. It's tap jacking.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Programmatically bring up the Control Center or something like that?

Comment: @JAL I'm trying to do the general thing I specified in my question: post touches, button, or key events to the system. I'm not trying to produce any specific action like invoking the control center. I'd like any touches I post to interact with any element in the system just like real touches, rather than just the current application. Essentially, I'd like to do the equivalent of using CGEventPost() in OS X.